# Como recuperar o option no click e selecionar o item que está no seu value?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<div class="escolher_temas">
    <form action="iframe.php" method="GET">
      <select name="escolhe_tema">
        <option value="http://z05.axitech.com.br">Tema 1</option>
        <option value="http://z06.axitech.com.br">Tema 2</option>
        <option value="http://z07.axitech.com.br">Tema 3</option>
        <option value="http://z08.axitech.com.br">Tema 4</option>
        <option value="http://z09.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z10.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z11.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z12.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z13.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z14.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z15.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z16.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z17.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z18.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z19.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
        <option value="http://z20.axitech.com.br">Tema 5</option>
      </select>
    </form> 
</div>

<iframe style="height: 587px;" class="full-screen-preview__frame" src="<?php echo $temaselecionado; ?>" name="preview-frame" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Gostaria de recuperar o value do option no click e jogá-lo no `$temaselecionado` para carregar a página escolhida. Repare que a variável é o ***source*** do iframe. Se puder fazer isso sem **PHP**, também serve.

Alguém pra me ajudar?

Comment: Quando dizes "no click" qual é o item que deve ser clicado? ou referes-te a selecionado, tipo `onchange` do select?

Comment: É o item do select que ao ser selecionado, clicado, sei lá vai carregar o value dentro do iframe no src !!!! Espero ter respondido a pergunta que não compreendi muito bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
document.querySelector('select[name="escolhe_tema"]').addEventListener('change', function(){
   var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    iframe.src = this.value;
});
```

Este código vai detetar o evento `change` quando uma option mudar e aplicar na iFrame o value do select.

Ele vai atribuir ao `src` do select o `url` que está no value. **Porém** esses links que sugeres parecem [não permitir serem mostrados dentro de um iFrame](http://jsfiddle.net/cfx4gzry/). Se esse dominio fôr do mesmo dominio que a página mãe tens de usar caminhos relativos, senão não vai dar sem carregar a página no PHP e "copiar" o conteúdo.

Comment: Eu percebi que os sources não estão sendo carregados que são subdomínios do meu domínio. Como eu resolvo isso?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius nesse caso tira o dominio da url e usa só `/oresto/do/caminho.html`

Answer (score 1):

Com jQuery, pode fazer assim:

```
$("select[name=escolhe_tema]").change(function() {
    var $iframe = $("iframe[name=preview-frame]");
    $iframe.attr("src", $(this).val());
});
```